# Run excel VBA function when sheet is clicked

Tags: excel, vba

I was wondering if there was a way to run a VBA script when I open a sheet in the workbook.

For example, I have a workbook called "Inventory" and I want to run an "InitiateInventoryValues" Function when the "View Inventory" sheet is opened.

Can anybody please help me on this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Double click the "Workbook" icon in VBE and use this event. It will trigger everytime you activate a different sheet by clicking its tab. If the tab is the one named "View Inventory", your code will run (once) when the sheet is activated:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)

If Sh.Name = "View Inventory" Then
    'Do your code
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Or better, use `Worksheet_Activate()` in the worksheet code (right-click on the Sheet name and click on "View code")

Comment: Nice -> JMax. Not sure why that didn't immediately occur to me! :p